# any logviewers that get directory name instead of the log file name

Tags: java, log-viewer

**Hi,** Is there any logviewers that we can open a directory to proccessing instead of a single file? so we can put several logs in the directory and the logviewer processes all the files and not just a single file.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com//p/otroslogviewer/) can import multiply files from one directory into one view. Log files can have different log format. You can open [remote logs (sftp, samba, http)](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/OpeningLogs).

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of OtrosLogViewer